# Windows Phone 7 emulator or device remote management on PC

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I am looking at ways I can get a Windows Phone 7 device/emulator on my PC screen for consultancy demos.

Developers can install a full blown Visual Studio 2010 and run an emulator.

However, is there a standalone version for non developers?

Or, is there software on the market that will allow you to plug the WP7 device into the PC and see the screen on the PC screen?

Basically, a requirement for doing demos/consultancy etc.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need vs to run the emulator, I'm pretty sure anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is a software that allow you to plug a WP7 into a PC and see the screen but it's only for Microsoft employees. 
You can find a alternative on XDA-Developers (like [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1134698)) but it's not perfect.

For a standalone emulator :

> Download the official SDK iso, mount or unpack it and then install either sde_xde2-enu.msi or sde_xde2x64-enu.msi - that's it.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=666610&page=11

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570

Install the sdk it will install vs express but the emulator can run on its own.  You can use the deployment tool to get apps on it.  Some things like mail won't work but you should be able to demo apps just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Answer number two is correct.  When you register as a developer with MS, you can download all of the development tools.  An emulator is included in the Express edition of Visual Studio which comes with the SDK.